# Two has_many_through Relationships To Same Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join, model, has-many-through

I have a `Contributor` Model and a `Resource` Model. In a simple world I would have the following setup:

```
class Resource

   has_many :authorships
   has_many :contributors, through: :authorships

end

class Contributor

   has_many :authorships
   has_many :resources, through: :authorships

end
```

However, my requirements have changed. A contributor can now either be an editor of a resource or an author of a resource. A `Contributor` can be an `Editor` of one resource and the `Author` of another. So it seems I have two ways to handle this requirement:

1. Add some kind of `is_editor?` attribute to my `Authorships` join model and effectively annotate each relationship.
2. Create a second join model – `Editorship`:

   ```
    class Resource
      has_many :authorships
      has_many :editorships
      has_many :contributors, through: :authorships
      has_many :contributors, through: :editorships

    end

    class Contributor
      has_many :authorships
      has_many :editorships
      has_many :resources, through: :authorships
      has_many :resources, through: :editorships
    end
   ```

**Which is the most sensible approach, or is there another approach I'm missing?**

Comment: The first case is supported by Rails polymporphic association, but I think the first question is do you need/want to support a `Contributor` which is simultaneously an author and an editor?

Comment: Both `Editors` and `Authors` are identical. They are interchangeable in every way. I don't want to Subclass and set up a Polymorphic relationship as this feels wrong. It seems to me that a Join describes the relationship much more clearly. I would also end up with a lot of duplication as the same data would be represented as both Author and Editor.

Comment: My question was whether a person can be an editor AND and author for the same resource.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Sorry. I misunderstood. I suppose this is possible, though looking through my dataset it doesn't occur. A Contributor can certainly be an Editor on one resource and an Author on another, but I think its unlikely they will be both Editor and Author of the same resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your clarification, I would use the first approach, but instead of just introducing an `is_editor` boolean for `Authorship`, you might want to the generalize the language and the concept and instead use `ResourceContributorship` with a `contributor_type` field which could now be either `:author` or `:editor`, but could be extended in the future.